# How to copy exactly same schema of one table to another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, schema

Initially, I'll be storing all columns of source table to single variable using stored procedure(SP1). This SP1 is called inside SP2 and that variable is inserted into destination table.

I know the approach but stuck in implementing it.

```
-- SP1
Create procedure insert_data
AS
Declare @data nvarchar(60)
Begin
EXEC get 
--Here i have to insert
END
Go
```

--SP2

```
Create procedure get_column 

AS

Declare 
    @e_id int , @e_name nvarchar(20) , @d_id int,@res nvarchar(50)

Begin

    SET @e_id =(select Emp_ID  from Dim_Employee where Emp_Name='Cathy');

    SET @e_name  =(select Emp_Name   from Dim_Employee where emp_id=101);

    SET @d_id  =(select Dept_ID  from Dim_Employee where emp_name='Cathy');

    SET @res ='@e_id , @e_name , @d_id';

    return @res

END
Go
```

Comment: Please refrain from using images. Copy and paste your code in the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have destination table:

```
insert into DestTbl(emp_id, dept_id, ...)
select emp_id, dept_id, ...
from Dim_Employee d
where ...
```

if you dont and wish to create it

```
select emp_id, dept_id, ...
into DestTbl
from Dim_Employee d
where ...
```

if you still want to use variables

```
insert into DestTbl(emp_id, dept_id)
values (@emp_id, @dept_id, ...)
```

is this what you're asking for?

INSERT statement on msdn:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx